# I have a server running on ec2 but I cant connect to the localhost 8085. Any suggestions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, localhost

I have a server running on ec2 but I cant connect to the localhost 8085. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is supposed to be listening on 8085?

Comment: What is the error ? Where is the screenshot ? What is configured on 8085 ? Given in the question is `localhost`, the issue is on OS level rather on AWS level.

Comment: @kintuparantu I am pretty much sure that the screen shot wont help you but feel free to look at it. no error!!! I just cant connect! Instead of screen shot i copied the webpage error

Comment: @kintuparantu This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 8085
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Connection Refused means the no service is listening on 8085 port.

Comment: @kintuparantu hmm but my db server instance is up an running and it is set for 8085!

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure your setup has the following:

- There is an [elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) attached to the instance, or it has a public IP address.
- The [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) allows incoming traffic on the correct port.
- The [network ACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) of the subnet that allow for the needed inbound and outbound traffic, or you're using the non-existent/default ACLs, which allow all inbound/outbound traffic.
- An [Internet Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) is in the same VPC as the instance.
- There is a rule in the subnet's [route table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) that sends internet-bound traffic to the Internet Gateway.

You may also find [this AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-attach-igw-vpc/) helpful for using the Internet Gateway in your VPC.